# Cannot find namespace 'ctx' error when creating Context with react - typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic4

I'm working on a project with `react` using `typescript` and I'm having a bad time figuring out why this error is happening, basically, I can't use any `createContext` examples that I found on the internet because of this.
This one specifically I got from here: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet I'm trying to use the same that is showing in the Context section.

```
import * as React from "react";

export function createCtx<A>(defaultValue: A) {
type UpdateType = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<typeof defaultValue>>;
const defaultUpdate: UpdateType = () => defaultValue;
const ctx = React.createContext({
    state: defaultValue,
    update: defaultUpdate
});
function Provider(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
    const [state, update] = React.useState(defaultValue);
    return <ctx.Provider value={{ state, update }} {...props} />;
}
return [ctx, Provider] as [typeof ctx, typeof Provider];
}
```

The issue is that everytime it says that there's this error
Cannot find namespace `ctx` in the line:

```
        return <ctx.Provider value={{ state, update }} {...props} />;
```

I'm still not able to figure out why, someone can see if I'm doing something wrong here? This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "dom.iterable",
  "esnext"
],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"strict": false,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "preserve",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"strictNullChecks": false
},
"include": [
"src"
]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seem the problem is in the configuration file. I was able to compile it on typescript playground. I cannot add the link here as it is too long. Where is you **tsconfig.json** located?

Answer (score 577, accepted):

Your file extension is most likely `.ts` instead of `.tsx`.

Therefore TypeScript is interpreting `<ctx.Provider` as cast and tries to find a type `Provider` in the namespace `ctx`.

Comment: Why does every Tutorial talking about `<context.Provider` use files like context/xyz.js instead of .jsx?

Comment: @Dollique Because typescript and javascript are not the same. Just to simplify javascript is not paying attention to the details but typescript does.

Comment: @Rarblack I was asking about js instead of jsx. Many Tutorials use .js files, which is the reason why I used .ts instead of .tsx in my case.