# useContext gives the error Cannot find namespace 'SideNavContext'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to use useContext hook, my context and provider file looks like this:

```
import { createContext, useState, ReactNode, useContext } from 'react';

interface SideNavContextType {
  isOpen: boolean;
  toggleSideNav: () => void;
}

export const SideNavContext = createContext<SideNavContextType>({
  isOpen: false,
  toggleSideNav: () => {},
});

export const useSideNav = () => {
  return useContext(SideNavContext);
};

export const SideNavProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleSideNav = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const value = {
    isOpen,
    toggleSideNav,
  };

  return (
    <SideNavContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</SideNavContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I'm getting an error with this line :

```
 <SideNavContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</SideNavContext.Provider>
```

the error is Cannot find namespace 'SideNavContext'. I have no clue why this is happening....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find namespace 'ctx' error when creating Context with react - typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242264/cannot-find-namespace-ctx-error-when-creating-context-with-react-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change my file name to end with tsx for this to work...